# How to use php in a .tpl file prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I just integrated a web-marchant plugin on my prestashop website, and one of the requirement of the web marchant is that i show a message either error or success message after an order as been submitted.So from the url i can get the action if successful or not. And from what i have read from around here i need to change

this :

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'Smarty.class.php');

global $smarty;
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

to this:

```
require_once(_PS_SMARTY_DIR_.'SmartyBC.class.php');

global $smarty;
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

And this i already did,then i added this to the page i want to display the response i get from the $_GET[] variable.

```
{php}
/**
*@authour 
*@return Order response
*4/15/2015
**/
    echo urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['gtpay_error']));
    echo '<br>';
    echo urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['gtpay_tranid']));
{/php}
```

but still no luck,it output the code as it is.What might i be doing please.
Thanks in advance

Now this is the php script am adding to the page:

```
{php}
        {$smarty.get.gtpay_error}
    {urldecode(base64_decode($smarty.get.gtpay_error))};
    {'<br>'}
    {urldecode(base64_decode($_GET['gtpay_tranid']))};
{/php}
```

then it throws error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/thelibra/public_html/tools/smarty/SmartyBC.class.php(464) : eval()'d code on line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{$smarty.get.gtpay_error}
```

$_GET is a reserved variable for Smarty, check this link for more information :
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl

Comment: i get error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/thelibra/public_html/tools/smarty/SmartyBC.class.php(464) : eval()'d code on line 2.Please look up at my edit

Comment: You still have $_GET in your code, replace by this `{urldecode(base64_decode($smarty.get.gtpay_tranid))};`

Answer (score 0):

Found out that my answer was pretty simple. i just had to remove the {php}{/php} tags, because the page somehow already handles that for me.